# Pages with session_start() don't load when server-sent event is running

Tags: php, session, server-sent-events

I'm working on a little project to make a 1v1 chat system. I wanted to work on a project where I could put `Server-Sent Events` to good use. It's been working pretty well, but recently I have been making some changes to the code so that in general the chat would be more efficient.

When I have the event source running I run into a weird issue. When I try to go to any other PHP page that has session_start() it doesn't load.

My event source script looks something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require "connect.php";
    require "user.php";

    header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

    set_time_limit(1200);

    $ms = 5000;
    //SOME MORE VARIABLES HERE

    while (1) {
        echo "data: SSESSION " . $_SESSION["conversation" . $_GET["id"]];
        echo "\n\n";

            /*CHAT SCRIPT HERE*/

        ob_flush();
        flush();
        usleep($ms * 1000);
    }
?>
```

What the session should return is the number of rows for the conversation. It does indeed.

If I go to `test.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION["conversation121643"];
?>
```

While the `Server-Sent Event` is running, this page just continues loading until I cancel the event.

I tried using the `ob_flush` function, but that doesn't fix anything.

I have no clue why i'm having this issue. And I hope there is a fix for it.

Comment: try removing  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

Comment: @EtienneLepage-Lepitre That doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: It works when I take the: `session_start();` out of the event source script. But I need it.

Comment: does $_SESSION["conversation121643"]; has data in it?

Comment: @EtienneLepage-Lepitre Yes, it has the number of rows for the conversation which at the moment is 54.

Comment: what you are saying is that test.php does not occur to print anything?

Comment: It doesn't print anything as long as the Server-Sent Event request is running. The page just loads, so its waiting for something, but i'm not sure what it is waiting for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33381/discussion-between-etienne-lepage-lepitre-and-shawn31313)

Answer (score 2):

PHP has exclusive lock around session. Only one process at a time can use it. This is usually unnoticeable because PHP processes start and end quickly, but with SSE you're keeping the session open forever and all other PHP processes will wait until SSE process ends.

You can execute `session_write_close()` to release the session to other processes.