# How can I avoid blocking of selects if there is a transaction ongoing?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have some InnoDB tables and a script that starts a transaction. Within this transaction different rows of one table gets updated, other rows will be inserted into another table and many selects are performed. This must happen reliably so I use a default transaction with REPEATABLE READ as the isolation level. This transaction may take some time.

Now, when other scripts (web page requests) get executed at the same time they do some selects at the database. Unfortunately, those selects wait until the transaction has ended since they read from the same tables. The selected data can be the updated data of the transaction but can also be other data.

This blocking is what I'd like to avoid. I'd like to show the web page to the user immediately and cannot wait for the transaction (one or two seconds would be acceptable, but the transaction sometimes is much longer).

So how can I do selects? I guess that the data may not always be accurate then. But this is better then let the user wait for 20 seconds.

Should I

- use 'FOR UPDATE' or 'LOCK IN SHARE MODE' with the selects in the transaction?
- use another isolation level?
- put the reading selects also in a transaction?
- do something different?

I think this is a very common requirement, but I couldn't find a simple answer yet.

Note: next thing would be to secure concurrent write transactions. But for now I just want to make sure that at least parallel reads don't get blocked during the transaction.

Comment: @iLikeMySql What do you mean? I just see that selects outside the transaction are waiting until the transaction has completed. The transaction uses UPDATE, INSERT and SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is not a real answer but I thought I should tell what I have found out:

It did not have anything to do with the MySQL actions, I guess. It actually was hanging PHP requests. That is, when the first PHP call started the long ongoing transaction, further PHP calls to other pages have hanged. And the reason why they hanged was that the **session** was locked by the first request! [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) did not work anymore. Just when the first request has completed (or timed out), further requests were going to work again.

Since the PHP call with long transaction did not need to write anything into the session I just close the session with [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) in this call. Now, further requests do not hang anymore.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18561641/57091) was the hint for me.

Conclusion: the database selects were not blocked.